# Home Up button overlapped somehow

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have situation like shown on image:
[image]

I'm using fragments, and login fragment is shown on this image.
This is main activity layout's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:contentDescription="@string/welcome_app_description"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/test"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/welcome_activity_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Theme I'm using:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TransparentToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

And this is fragment that is shown in main activity layout's `LinearLayout` with id of `welcome_activity_root`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="xxx.LoginFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_email_til"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="@string/email_example"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    ...
```

Does anybody have a clue what seems to be overlapping "back arrow" or home up button?